# Deploy gatsby on nginx has wrong redirect address when refresh and brings out port number?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a website, and deploy the site on nginx in docker container. The problem is when I refresh the site the chrome address bar brings out the port number and redirects wrong.

I am a front-end programmer and don't have any server permission, so i can try nothing on the back end. On the server side I have already tried editing `nginx` config file but without success.

This is the website address:

```
www.haetek.com/case
```

If you refresh the page it brings out port number 8181.

```
www.haetek.com:8181/case
```

I expect normal address redirect.

this is `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: 'bitnami/nginx:latest'
    ports:- '80:8181'- '443:8443'
    volumes:- ./conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf- ./certs:/certs- ./data:/app
```

Comment: Can anybody give a tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This qustion is solved just add a slash at the end of the address,

this address

```
www.haetek.com/case
```

to this address

```
www.haetek.com/case/
```

I don't know the detail why it solved the problem. but it worked.